# How to change watir chrome pref default_directory to amazon s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir, rails-activestorage

### storage.yml

```
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
 service: S3
 access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
 secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
 region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
 bucket: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] %>

confi/enviroments/development.rb
-----------------------------------------------
# Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon


Watir Chrome Downaload
-----------------------------------------
prefs = {
  download: {
    prompt_for_download: false,
    default_directory: '/path/to/dir'
  }
}

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs}
```

---

**My query how to do i set  default_directory ro amazon  in pref for watir chrom download
**
is this correct --

```
prefs = {
  download: {
    prompt_for_download: false,
    default_directory: amazon
  }
}
```

Need help :)

[enter link description here](http://watir.com/guides/downloads/)

Comment: I tired ```prefs = {
  download: {
    prompt_for_download: false,
    default_directory: amazon
  }
```  But it leads to development of new folder in my rails app and save downloaded file there

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the directory name then it will create the directory in your current directory. Give the full path there. It will work perfectly. I am using this and it's working perfectly for me.

Comment: Could you please code sample how exactly to give path to s3 here. `default_directory: amazon` what should be replaced here for direct s3 path.  so i can use in  `prefs = { download: { prompt_for_download: false, default_directory: amazon }`

Comment: As i am able to transfer file from my directory to S3 using custom method , but i was looking more , how to give that path so it goes direclty to s3 instead of calling method and then sending it